# Clickhouse migration rollback

Tags: migration, clickhouse

I'm currently working with ClickHouse and need to rollback some migrations due to an issue in my application, but I couldn't find a direct way to rollback migrations in ClickHouse using this tool.

I would like to know if there is a recommended approach or workaround to rollback migrations in ClickHouse. Specifically, I am looking for a way to modify the schema_migrations table to achieve this.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried to look at the schema but its appearance left me bewildered[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4guq5.png)

Comment: Which exactly tool do you mean?

Comment: i use dBeaver tool

Comment: and go-migrate tool @Slach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use
https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate
you need to write down migration
you need always use ON CLUSTER clause for your DDL if you have multiple servers in clickhouse cluster

then look
https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/tree/master/database/clickhouse

use
`?x-migrations-table-engine=MergeTree` in connection URL

if your migration failure with default golang-migrate settings

you need manually convert your TinyLog `schema_migrations` table to MergeTree

use

```sql
CREATE TABLE mergetree_schema_migrations ON CLUSTER 'cluster-name'
ENGINE=MergeTree() ORDER BY tuple() 
AS SELECT * FROM schema_migrtions;
```

after it you can change records in mergetre_schema_migrations
via mutations

```
ALTER TABLE mergetree_schema_migrations UPDATE / DELETE ... WHERE ..
```

look details

- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/update
- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/delete
- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter#synchronicity-of-alter-queries

after it you can drop exists `schema_migrations` and rename `mergetree_schema_migrations`

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schema_migrations ON CLUSTER 'cluster-name' SYNC;

RENAME TABLE mergetree_schema_migrations 
ON CLUSTER 'cluster-name' TO schema_migrations;
```